# read html file with python at Zapier

Tags: python, zapier

I'm trying to read the contents of an html file using Python Code in Zapier.

input data:

[image]

```
with open('name') as f:
contents = f.read()
print(contents)
```

I'm doing my best to copy and paste from other tutorials, but I can't seem to get it.

Comment: Is there an error that you get? The code as presented would raise an `IndentationError`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to read your file from a different directory and you are facing issue with it try using below approach.
Check the below Code To get you an idea

```
import os
os.chdir('c:\mypath') # add your path here
with open("name.html", 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    contents = f.read()
    print(contents)
```

It should give you the below output on console
[image: Output On Console]